# auto check checkboxes for matching result in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make it so that when my ajax call is returned with an object/array, I can match up the results to checkboxes so that if there is a match I auto check the boxes

Here are my checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name='Magazine' data-md-icheck  />
<input type="checkbox" name='Website' data-md-icheck  />
<input type="checkbox" name='Advertisement' data-md-icheck  />
```

Now my ajax call is successful

I get back:

```
0: {}
type: "Magazine"
1: {}
type: "Website"
```

so in my ajax success, what I would like to do is take any result in that object, whether just one or all 3, and if the type matches the 'name' of the checkbox I want to check that box.

Here is my function that makes the successful ajax call. I just can't figure out a way to loop the return that I get so that I can match up any result that comes through

```
function getDetails(ID) {
    console.log(ID);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/details",
        data: {ID:ID},
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

        },
    });
};
```

So in this case, how would I modify my ajax success to check the magazine and website boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS and simple solution to this:-

```
// Assuming you get the response as an array of objects, which has a key as type
success: function (data) {
    data.forEach(obj => {
        let ele = document.getElementsByName(obj.type)[0];
        if(ele) {
          ele.checked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle it:

```
function getDetails(ID) {
  console.log(ID);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/details",
    data: {ID:ID},
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var item = data[i].type;
        var checkbox = $('input[name="'+item+'"]);
        if (checkbox.length){
          checkbox.prop('checked', true);
        }
      } 
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: thank you, I did this and used logging to confirm that the item is set properly, which it is. It matches the name of the checkbox but it still isn't checked. This is in laravel if that makes any difference

Comment: it is possible the checkboxes (being part of the DOM) are not rendered at the time your AJAX success function tries to find and check them, which could be solved by ensuring this AJAX function runs after the DOM is ready, i.e. put it inside `$(window).on('load', function(){ })`

Answer (score 0):

Assume the result is pure text exactly the same as you provided (ES6+)

```js
let a = 'result...'
            ['Magazine', 'Website', 'Advertisement'].filter(item => a.indexOf(item) != -1).forEach(item => {
                let inputs = document.getElementsByName(item)
                if (inputs.length > 0)
                    inputs[0].checked = true
            })
```